# PowerShell Form Checkbox Not Executing Script After Check

Tags: powershell, checkbox

I created a form with checkboxes and wanted the script to execute the lines if the checkboxes are selected and I press OK. But for some reason it's not opening. I used both `$checkbox1 -eq $true` and `$checkbox1.checked`.

Please take a look at my script, is it place it in the wrong spot? (The last part is the code after you press OK)

**Script :**

```
$formPrinterInstallerProg = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$checkbox2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$checkbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$label2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$label1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$Label = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$buttonOK = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState' 

$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($checkbox2)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($checkbox1)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($label2)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($label1)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($Label)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.AcceptButton = $buttonOK
$formPrinterInstallerProg.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.ClientSize = '545, 362'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.MaximizeBox = $False
$formPrinterInstallerProg.MinimizeBox = $False
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Name = 'formPrinterInstallerProg'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Text = 'Printer Installer Program'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.add_Load($formPrinterInstallerProg_Load)
#
# checkbox2
#
$checkbox2.Location = '12, 101'
$checkbox2.Name = 'checkbox2'
$checkbox2.Size = '104, 24'
$checkbox2.TabIndex = 5
$checkbox2.Text = 'checkbox2'
$checkbox2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$checkbox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$checkbox2.add_CheckedChanged($checkbox2_CheckedChanged)
#
# checkbox1
#
$checkbox1.Location = '13, 71'
$checkbox1.Name = 'checkbox1'
$checkbox1.Size = '104, 24'
$checkbox1.TabIndex = 4
$checkbox1.Text = 'checkbox1'
$checkbox1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$checkbox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$checkbox1.add_CheckedChanged($checkbox1_CheckedChanged)
#
# label2
#
$label2.AutoSize = $True
$label2.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 11pt'
$label2.Location = '12, 27'
$label2.Name = 'label2'
$label2.Size = '46, 22'
$label2.TabIndex = 3
$label2.Text = 'label2'
$label2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
#
# label1
#
$label1.AutoSize = $True
$label1.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 11pt'
$label1.Location = '12, 327'
$label1.Name = 'label1'
$label1.Size = '46, 22'
$label1.TabIndex = 2
$label1.Text = 'label1'
$label1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
#
# Label
#
$Label.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 11pt'
$Label.Location = '12, 9'
$Label.Name = 'Label'
$Label.Size = '320, 18'
$Label.TabIndex = 1
$Label.Text = 'label'
$Label.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$Label.add_Click($Label_Click)
#
# buttonOK
#
$buttonOK.Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'
$buttonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
$buttonOK.Location = '458, 327'
$buttonOK.Name = 'buttonOK'
$buttonOK.Size = '75, 23'
$buttonOK.TabIndex = 0
$buttonOK.Text = '&OK'
$buttonOK.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$buttonOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$formPrinterInstallerProg.ResumeLayout()


$buttonOK_Click = {
    if($checkbox1 -eq $True) {
        Write-Host 'Checked'
        Start-Process C:\windows\System32\notepad.exe   
    }
}
Show-New-Form_psf | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no click event attached to button and there is no function `$checkbox1_CheckedChanged`. See following working demo:

```
$formPrinterInstallerProg = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$checkbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$buttonOK = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($checkbox1)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
$formPrinterInstallerProg.AcceptButton = $buttonOK
$formPrinterInstallerProg.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.ClientSize = '545, 362'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.MaximizeBox = $False
$formPrinterInstallerProg.MinimizeBox = $False
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Name = 'formPrinterInstallerProg'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$formPrinterInstallerProg.Text = 'Printer Installer Program'
#
# checkbox1
#
$checkbox1.Location = '13, 71'
$checkbox1.Name = 'checkbox1'
$checkbox1.Size = '104, 24'
$checkbox1.TabIndex = 4
$checkbox1.Text = 'checkbox1'
$checkbox1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$checkbox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$checkbox1.add_CheckedChanged({
    if ($checkbox1.Checked){
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("I'm checked now!", "My Dialog Box")
    }
})
#
# buttonOK
#
$buttonOK.Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'
$buttonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
$buttonOK.Location = '458, 327'
$buttonOK.Name = 'buttonOK'
$buttonOK.Size = '75, 23'
$buttonOK.TabIndex = 0
$buttonOK.Text = '&OK'
$buttonOK.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
$buttonOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$buttonOk.add_Click({
    if ($checkbox1.Checked){
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("I'm checked!", "My Dialog Box")
    }
})
$formPrinterInstallerProg.ResumeLayout()

$formPrinterInstallerProg.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Hint: make sure your example is minimal - you need only button and checkbox to show your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot about click event into the form, I thought just calling the variable out of no where would work.